# Is my HDD damaged?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm having an issue with my laptop's internal HDD and need some advice.

I think there may be an issue with it, but chdsk and a long check with SeaTools hasn't turned up anything.

I have two drives in the laptop, an SSD (which the OS is on), and the HDD with the issue. All the HDD is used for is storing video files. I can access the files fine, but once the drive is in use for a while (say 30mins into a film), my system freezes and hangs. The same would happen if I copied a large amount of files from the HDD to SSD.

Never any issues unless I go near files on the HDD.

OS is Windows 10.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Thank you. Just used SeaTool to do a SMART check and it passed.

Comment: It's possible the internal power supply is insufficient to run both drives. You might try running it alone, or in an external USB enclosure with its own power supply, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Insten-EXTERNAL-HARD-DRIVE-ENCLOSURE/dp/B004S62TBU.

Comment: Ooof, that would be a pain, as I don't fancy having the replace the laptop's power supply. Any thoughts on a way to test this without removing the disk?